# Windows Mobile app copy file to desktop?

Tags: windows, mobile, rapi

Is it possible to write a WinMo app that copies files from the device to the attached desktop? I know RAPI works from the desktop to the mobile, but I'd like to turn that around if I can.

Answer (score 0):

There was a download called CERApi which is a Managed wrapper around the RAPI calls, it was on [WintoolZone.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20220908041705/https://wintoolzone.com/), here's an example on the [blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20091212184704/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/khanna/archive/2005/04/01/27888.aspx) on how to use it. Unfortunately, the WinToolZone's CERapi cannot be found, I am still searching for the DLL as download...

I will edit this answer again accordingly once I find the download link

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Thanks Tom. It looks like CERapi is similar to the OpenNetCF Desktop Communication wrappers at codeplex. I've got working code using this library. The problem is that it seems to be desktop centric. I'm really looking to find something that let's me push from the mobile, not from the desktop. I suspect that this may not be possible.